# Ctrl+Shift+Page{Up,Down} in tmux

Tags: terminal, tmux, xterm

Trying to make C-S-PageUp and C-S-PageDown work in tmux but no success so far.
Here are my config steps:

```
bind-key -n C-PageUp previous-window
bind-key -n C-PageDown next-window
bind-key -n C-S-PageUp swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-PageDown swap-window -t +1
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

(C-PageUp and C-PageDown works).

When I <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+PageDown</kbd>, nothing happens. When I <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+PageUp</kbd> my terminal scrolls up before tmux is launched.

I have other config items, but they should not have an influence.
I am using `xterm` on Ubuntun 16.04, I have the `TERM` env var set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: These are handled by xterm itself (just as `S-PageUp` and `S-PageDown` without `Ctrl`) and don't generate any escape sequence at all. You should somehow try to configure your xterm not to handle these but rather send some escape sequence (I'm not an xterm guy, I don't know how to do this).

Comment: try `alacritty` terminal emulator, i see that it doesnt bind to anything `C-S-PageDown` or `C-S-PageUp`